# Embedding Another APK with My app and opening it in my app, and also installing it at the same time when i install my app. Can i Do This?

Tags: android, coding-style, apk

For Example I have app A ( this one is mine) And B (i have this app's apk),I want that When Users install my App A, my app B is also installed and they can acces the App B from my app only, Can this be possible ? .Please Guys Help, can anyone answer this ?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not easy，if your app is a system application，maybe you can do it。Or your app have root permissions。
1、when installed your app ,unzip App B to SD or other place;
2、when opened your app,you can install App B in background,and hide the launcher icon of AppB。
This need you know AppB's package_name,Action ,so that you can launch it in your app.

Comment: It's not a system application